# Create image with bullets

Tags: php, css

I've an image like http://prntscr.com/3etg6t. I would like this in my application. But the circles (with colors) I would like to be able to change them. So, the values and the colors. But I've now idea how I could aclompish this. Is this possible with some CSS, or should I generate it with PHP?

Ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `position: relative` on the container and `position: absolute` on the bullets.

**CSS**:

```
#body {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/5cXq5VT.jpg') no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}

.bullet {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="bullet" style="top: 50px; left: 310px;">:)</div>
    <div class="bullet" style="top: 135px; left: 290px;">no</div>
    <div class="bullet" style="top: 135px; left: 325px;">no</div>
    <div class="bullet" style="top: 240px; left: 300px;">nope</div>
</div>
```

**Result**:

[image]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cNuwV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **imagemapster**.

Here's a link for the demo projects page for this plug-in - http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html

Here's a project I've used it recently - http://male.fitnessdays.bg/

This should be the exact result yoyu're looking for. You will just have to create your polygons and define the colors and effects you want to achieve.